# Parenthesis(like) precendence order in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

i' ve multiple **|** used in django templates, and i' d like to know is it somehow possible to force a precendence order (like parenthesis in arithmetics)?

I' ve a pretty much complicated data structure where from i' d like to use the date with 8 digits, but the month and day is stored without the leading zero:

```
{% url 'diary' year.0|add_str:month.0|add_str:forloop.counter %}
```

would result only **201847** instead of **20180407** . A correct way would be somehow:

```
year.0|add_str:(month.0|stringformat:'02d')|add_str:(forloop.counter|stringformat:'02d')
```

, but of course the parenthesis does not work here.

How can i achieve my goal in the django template language? Of course an easy solution would be to write a filter, but i' d like to know the possible solution in the template language.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use variables to store the parts of a bigger expression (e.g. you can store `month.0|stringformat:'02d'` and `forloop.counter|stringformat:'02d'`, and then just replace expressions with variables).